# SQL Server Management - Index propertiers keyboard shortcut?

Tags: sql-server, keyboard, ssms

While doing development in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), I frequently want to check the properties of a number of index on a specific table from within the *Object Explorer*:

[image: Screenshot from SSMS]

Pulling up the index properties to see the columns included in the index, one can double-click the index name in *Object Explorer*, or alternatively use the *[Menu Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)* and then using *Up* to select *Properties*, and then hitting *Enter*.

I checked the [SQL Server Management Studio Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx) list, but did not manage to find the answer to my question.

Is there a one-key shortcut that could be used to pull up the index properties instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried to find any context menus registered in SSMS concerning Index in Object explorer, but unfortunately it looks like that it is 100% built dynamically. So it is impossible to assign a shortcut. Generally, you can assign shortcut on any command, that is registered as menu command in SSMS. But no luck here.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so.  Usually if someone wants that level of speed in accessing information about indexes, they'll just issue an `sp_helpindex` command in T-SQL or query `sys.indexes` for the information they want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately I'm dealing with Navision tables, meaning I have to deal with horrible table names (I.e. `Wacky Company Name$No_ Series Line`, some with 18-20 indexes on them. I'm (ideally) hoping to somehow bypass the whole use of the mouse altogether.